# packages / import statment

Tags: python, python-module

I have virtual environment package structured as following:

```
apps/
    __init__.py
    main_app.py (storing the execution function)
    st/
        speedtest.py
        __init__.py
    quota/
        quota.py
        __init__.py
main.py
```

In some cases I will the program from `apps/main_app.py` or `main.py` which is located at the root path but the execution function still at `apps/main_app.py`.

Each time to change the import statement from the modules.

ex.

If I run from the `apps/main_app.py`, I use:

```py
from st import speedtest
from quota import quota.py
```

If I run the imported execution function of `apps/main_app.py` from `main.py`, I have to change `apps/main_app.py` importing functions

```py
from . st import speedtest
from . quota import quota.py
```

I solved it by saving the package at `Lib\site-packages`

Is this the best practice? Or is there another solution to keep the package on the root directory and run from main.py without any modifications.

Running the program from main.py without any modifications, but I got error: `can't not import speedtest from st`.

Comment: What does your main.py look like? Is it `import app.main_app` and then `mani_app.main_function()`?

Comment: from st.st_main import main
import asyncio

asyncio.run(main())

Answer (score -1):

Put the following in `apps/main_app.py`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from st import speedtest
    from quota import quota
else:
    from .st import speedtest
    from .quota import quota
```

This way, if you're running `main_app.py` directly, it'll use the absolute imports specified in the `if` block. Otherwise, if `apps.main_app` has been imported from `main.py`, it'll use the relative imports in the `else` block.